# Pandas, matplotlib and plotly - how to fix series legend?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I'm trying to create an interactive plotly graph from pandas dataframes.

However, I can't get the **legends** displayed correctly.

### Here is a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.plotly as py

# sign into the plotly api
py.sign_in("***********", "***********")

# create some random dataframes
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=8)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), index=dates, columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 1), index=dates, columns=['B'])
df1.index.name = 'date'
df2.index.name = 'date'
```

Now I attempt to plot the dataframes using plotly.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
df1.plot(y='A', ax=ax)
df2.plot(y='B', ax=ax)
    
py.iplot_mpl(fig, filename='random')
```

Notice there is no legend

[image: Plotly - no legend]

#### Edit:

Based on suggestions below I have added an `update` dict. Although this does display the legend, it messes up the plot itself:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
df1.plot(y='A', ax=ax)
df2.plot(y='B', ax=ax)
    
update = dict(
    layout=dict(
        annotations=[dict(text=' ')],  # rm erroneous 'A', 'B', ... annotations
        showlegend=True                # show legend 
    )
)
py.iplot_mpl(fig, update=update, filename='random')
```

[image]

#### Edit 2:

Removing the `annotations` entry from the `layout` dict results in the plot being displayed correctly, but the legend is not the `y` column name, but rather the `x` column name, the index name of the dataframe

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
    
df1.plot(y='A', ax=ax)
df2.plot(y='B', ax=ax)
    
update = dict(
    layout=dict(
        showlegend=True                # show legend 
    )
)
py.iplot_mpl(fig, update=update, filename='random')
```

This results in the following plot:

[image]

#### Edit 3:

I have found a way to override the legend text but it seems a bit klunky. Given that I've specified the dataframe column I want to plot:

```
df1.plot(y='A', ax=ax)
```

I would have expected that `y='A'` would result in `'A'` being used as the legend label.

It seems this is not the case, and while it is possible to override using the index label, as seen below, it just feels wrong.

**Is there a better way to achieve this result?**

```
update = dict(
    layout=dict(
        showlegend=True,
    ),
    data=[
        dict(name='A'),
        dict(name='B'),
    ]
)
py.iplot_mpl(fig, update=update, filename='random')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Legends don't convert well from matplotlib to plotly.

Fortunately, adding a plotly legend to a matplotlib plot is straight forward:

```
update = dict(
    layout=dict(
        showlegend=True  # show legend 
    )
)
py.iplot_mpl(fig, update=update)
```

See the full working [ipython notebook here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/update-showlegend.ipynb).

For more information, refer to the plotly [user guide](https://plot.ly/python/matplotlib-to-plotly-tutorial/#Careful,-matplotlib-is-not-perfect-(yet)).

Comment: `PlotlyDictKeyError: Invalid key, 'showlegend', for class, 'Figure'.`

Comment: what version of plotly are you using, coz your solution doesn't work for me? I've got 1.6.16, which seems to be the latest from pip

Comment: I'm afraid that still doesn't work. I've updated the question to include a full working example which should allow you to replicate the behaviour I'm seeing (if you so wish!) - Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually, I've removed the `annotations` entry you suggested, and that seems to work. What is the `annotations` part for?

Comment: My mistake. I was sure that the figure attached in an earlier version of this issue contained erroneously converted annotations (hence the `annotations` key-value in `update`).  The notebook has the full working solution http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/etpinard/plotly-misc-nbs/blob/master/update-showlegend.ipynb.

Comment: No, you are correct, apologies for that. I was trying to create a simple and working example to allow you to replicate what I was seeing. There was a piece in my example that I missed though - which is for the pandas dataframe's index to have a name. In this event the legend shows the index name rather than the `y` column name. I've updated the example.

Comment: thank you for your help. Even though I've found a way, I guess I've added my final edit to the question so that you guys at plotly (I'm assuming you're still at plotly - as per your [SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4068492/etpinard)) can see what I'm struggling with. If there's a better place to submit issues etc, please let me know.